# How to identify a group as a primitive group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

I have a problem identifying a group as a primitive group by using the function PrimitiveIdentification. Here is my code.

```
gap> l:=List(
[ [ [ [ Z(23)^0, 0*Z(23) ], [ Z(23), Z(23)^11 ] ], [ [ Z(23)^17, Z(23)^7 ], [ Z(23)^19, Z(23)^6 ] ]
        , [ [ Z(23)^11, 0*Z(23) ], [ 0*Z(23), Z(23)^11 ] ],
      [ [ Z(23), 0*Z(23) ], [ 0*Z(23), Z(23) ] ], [ [ Z(23)^2, Z(23)^10 ], [ Z(23)^0, Z(23)^0 ] ],
      [ [ Z(23)^18, Z(23)^10 ], [ Z(23)^0, Z(23) ] ] ] ], x->Subgroup(GL(2,23),x));
[ Group([ [ [ Z(23)^0, 0*Z(23) ], [ Z(23), Z(23)^11 ] ], [ [ Z(23)^17, Z(23)^7 ], [ Z(23)^19, Z(23)^6 ] ],
      [ [ Z(23)^11, 0*Z(23) ], [ 0*Z(23), Z(23)^11 ] ], [ [ Z(23), 0*Z(23) ], [ 0*Z(23), Z(23) ] ],
      [ [ Z(23)^2, Z(23)^10 ], [ Z(23)^0, Z(23)^0 ] ], [ [ Z(23)^18, Z(23)^10 ], [ Z(23)^0, Z(23) ] ] ]) ]
gap> h:=l[1];;
gap> g:=SemidirectProduct(h,GF(23)^2);
<matrix group of size 186208 with 7 generators>
gap> IsPrimitiveSolvable(g);
true
gap> PrimitiveIdentification(g);
Error, no method found! For debugging hints type ?Recovery from NoMethodFound
Error, no 1st choice method found for `PrimitiveIdentification' on 1 arguments at /opt/gap-v4.12.2/.libs/../lib/methsel2.g:249 called from
<function "HANDLE_METHOD_NOT_FOUND">( <arguments> )
 called from read-eval loop at *stdin*:372
type 'quit;' to quit to outer loop
brk>
```

So, in general, how to identify a group as a primitive group? Any explanation, references, suggestion and examples are appreciated.

Comment: According to the documentation at https://docs.gap-system.org/pkg/primgrp/doc/chap1_mj.html, this function *identifies* (gives a number to) a given *primitive permutation group*. By contrast your group $g$ is a *matrix group*. What do you mean by "identify as a primitive group"?

Comment: Note that any abstract group is a primitive group in many different ways: one per conjugacy class of maximal subgroup.

Comment: I would like to show my group $g$ is isomorphic to some PrimitiveGroup(23^2, n). By saying identification, I mean to find the n.

Comment: I see, you are considering the action of $g$ on the cosets of $h$. You need to tell GAP that. See https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap41.html and search for "FactorCosetAction".

Comment: `PrimitiveIdentification` requires the group to be a primitive group of permutations, not just a group that can be primitive in some action. You will need to convert to a permutation group, most likely by acting on the set of $23^2$ vectors.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your description in which way you want to consider $g$ as a primitive permutation group. But whatever it is, it must be by the action on cosets of a maximal subgroup. There are 5 of those:

```
gap> maxsubs:=MaximalSubgroupClassReps(g);;
gap> Length(maxsubs);
5
```

However, only 1 of the leads to a faithful permutation representation of your starting group:

```
gap> acts:=List(maxsubs,m->FactorCosetAction(g,m));;
gap> Number(acts, IsInjective);
1
```

We can identify the resulting primtive group:

```
gap> iso:=First(acts,IsInjective);;
gap> g0:=Image(iso);
<permutation group of size 186208 with 7 generators>
gap> PrimitiveIdentification(g0);
53
gap> NrMovedPoints(g0);
529
```

This is just the same as we get from the coset action on the cosets of the group $h$ inside $g$; indeed we can also work directly from that:

```
gap> h0:=Image(Embedding(g,1));
<matrix group of size 352 with 6 generators>
gap> PrimitiveIdentification(Image(FactorCosetAction(g,h0)));
53
```